# How to know, from what page form was submited xsl template

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I want to insert in my form some code, like `<input type="hidden" value="contact-form-1" name="getpage">` to get url of page, from which form was sent.

Problem is - site uses xsl templates and i don't know, how to make it with xsl.

I think, maybe it is possible with jquery something like

```
var page = location.href;

$('input.pagelink').html($page);
```

but will value of link pasted dynamic in html send with form?

**UPDATE**

i'm trying

```
<input type="hidden" id="system_page_from"  value="" />

 $(document).ready(function() {
      var page = location.href;

      $('#system_page_from').val(page);
      });
```

On frontend works good, **BUT**
The value doesn't send to email =( Where is mistake?
Help me please!

Comment: Use `val` - `$('input.pagelink').val($page);` as long as the input is inside the form tags, it will be posted.

Comment: *"but will value of link pasted dynamic in html send with form?"* - what happened when you tried it?

Comment: look at update please...the value i get don't send to email

Comment: @freedomn-m as i expected the value i get doesn't send to email

Comment: Err - what *email*?   There's nothing in the question about emails - it's about forms.

Answer (score 0):

So with right settings of email template this works

```
<input type="hidden" id="system_page_from"  value="" />
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var page = location.href;
      $('#system_page_from').val(page);
      });
```